# Safe measurement of spark voltages on a piezo-electric starter

Tags: high-voltage, spark

I'd like to estimate the actual generated spark voltage on a standard home-use piezo-electric lighter used for lighting gas stoves etc. Judging by the maximum spark distance of between 1 - 3 mm depending how the ground return path is positioned I'm estimating it is over 4KV but would be curious to measure it with a say a 100MHz or 200MHz CRO.

I'm not prepared to sacrifice the CRO inputs even though the probes have attenuation, so otherwise is a simple attenuator say x2 20dB in series, or some resistors in voltage divider configuration be enough?  Is it necessary to consider the voltage rating of the resistors used in the attenuation or is the power in the spark way to tiny to require such precautions?

Comment: Great idea. 200 MHz might not be enough to see the best bits, they go over 1 GHz. Still worth a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There *are* dedicated HV probes for that kind of work but the price is outside most people budget. However you can do it quite safely making a voltage divider with suitable resistors.

Power is not an issue in that application, piezo generators are relatively weak, however you may want to make something like a 1:1000 or 1:10000 divider. You can identify an high voltage resistor easily since they are quite long (some of these are about 10cm) for clearance/creepage purposes. Ohmite for example has *multiple* lines of these. I did an ignition transformer test fixture with them some years ago)

If you are worried about protecting your scope from wandering voltages (these are common with high voltage pulses) I recommend some varistor/TVS combination on the low side (and maybe a GDT for good measure). They *will* add some parasite capacitance so of course it's a tradeoff.

Alternatives: you can make a capacitive divider (even bigger and funnier) or maybe you could try with the probe used by auto shops for checking spark ignitions (usually capacitive pickups too). Since you essentially are measuring spark generators they should do the job.